How can I use Ansible to install all packages defined in a Brewfile?
I am trying to configure Ansible to install all the packages defined in my Brewfile, but I am getting the following error
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "brew bundle", "delta": "0:00:00.163639", "end": "2024-04-02 21:03:51.639762", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2024-04-02 21:03:51.476123", "stderr": "Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.\nAs Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all\nbuild scripts full access to your system.", "stderr_lines": ["Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.", "As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all", "build scripts full access to your system."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

This is what my files looks like
# bootstrap.yaml
- name: Bootstrap development environment
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:

- name: Install packages from Brewfile
    become: yes
    ansible.builtin.shell: brew bundle
    when: ansible_distribution == "MacOSX"

# Brewfile
brew "autoconf"
brew "docker", link: false

When I run
ansible-playbook --ask-become-pass bootstrap.yml

I get the above mentioned error.
What is the reason for this error?
By the way, I have installed the community.general collection from Ansible, and I already have Homebrew installed. AFAIK, brew bundle is still not available in Ansible, but I do not understand why the shell command is not available.

I don't have experience with MacOS, but the error is indicating that running brew as root  is no longer supported. Perhaps you have to add a become  directive to the task or user at play level.

What do you mean by the shell command is not available? It's not Ansible output, it's output of brew itself. The error clearly says that you're not supposed to use brew with sudo. @seshadri_c in this case become should be removed (it's already there), not added.

Ah yes @AlexanderPletnev, it was supposed to be become_user since become is specified.

@seshadri_c no. This playbook is being run locally - that implies that all Ansible-controlled processes will be executed on behalf of the same user by default - the same as how brew itself should be executed. There's no need to use become  and thus become_user at all in this case.

By removing the --ask-become-pass and become: yes can Homebrew still ask for admin password?

I agree @AlexanderPletnev.

Thanks for the comments. I have changed the file to
# bootstrap.yaml
- name: Bootstrap development environment
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:

- name: Install packages from Brewfile
  ansible.builtin.shell: brew bundle
  when: ansible_distribution == "MacOSX"

and I am now running with
ansible-playbook bootstrap.yml

without issues.
